# React - Checking active element on focus not behaving as expected

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a form input component where I am checking if the input is active to set the active class to the input's label:

```
import React, { forwardRef, ReactElement, ReactNode, HTMLProps, useImperativeHandle } from 'react'
import styles from './index.module.css'
import classNames from 'classnames'
import { IconFa } from '../icon-fa'
import { useStableId } from '../use-stable-id'

export interface Props extends HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement> {
  // An icon component to show on the left.
  icon?: ReactNode
  // A help text tooltip to show on the right.
  help?: string
  // A clear text tooltip to show on the right.
  clear?: string
  // Pass an onHelp click handler to show a help button.
  onHelp?: () => void
  // Pass an onClear click handler to show a clear button.
  onClear?: () => void
  errorMessage?: ReactNode
  label?: string
  hideLabel?: boolean
}

export const FormInput = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>(function FormInput(props, ref): ReactElement {
  const { id, icon, help, hideLabel, errorMessage, onHelp, onClear, ...rest } = props
  const internalRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
  useImperativeHandle<HTMLInputElement | null, HTMLInputElement | null>(ref, () => internalRef.current)
  const stableId = useStableId()
  const inputId = id ? id : stableId
  const active = document.activeElement === internalRef.current

  const inputClassName = classNames(
    styles.input,
    icon && styles.hasLeftIcon,
    (help || onHelp || onClear) && styles.hasRightIcon
  )

  const labelClassName = classNames(
    styles.label,
    Boolean(props.value) && styles.hasValue,
    props['aria-invalid'] && styles.hasError,
    active && styles.active,
    props.className
  )

  return (
    <div className={labelClassName}>
      {!hideLabel && (
        <label className={styles.labelText} htmlFor={inputId}>
          {props.label}
          {props.required && '*'}
        </label>
      )}
      <div className="relative">
        {icon && <div className={styles.leftIcon}>{icon}</div>}
        <input
          {...rest}
          id={inputId}
          ref={internalRef}
          aria-invalid={props['aria-invalid']}
          aria-label={props.hideLabel ? props.label : undefined}
          className={inputClassName}
        />
        {onClear && <ClearIcon {...props} />}
        {!onClear && (help || onHelp) && <HelpIcon {...props} />}
      </div>
      {props['aria-invalid'] && <span className={styles.error}>{errorMessage}</span>}
    </div>
  )
})

function HelpIcon(props: Props) {
  if (props.onHelp) {
    return (
      <button type="button" className={styles.rightIcon} aria-label={props.help} onClick={props.onHelp}>
        <IconFa icon={['far', 'info-circle']} title={props.help} />
      </button>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.rightIcon} title={props.help}>
      <IconFa icon={['far', 'info-circle']} />
    </div>
  )
}

function ClearIcon(props: Props) {
  return (
    <button type="button" className={styles.rightIcon} aria-label={props.clear} onClick={props.onClear}>
      <IconFa icon={['far', 'times']} title={props.clear} />
    </button>
  )
}
```

But, when I do it like this, the active class is added to label only when I start typing not when the input is focused. Right now, since I am using `:focus` selector on input, input gets active class on focus, while label gets it only after typing. How can I fix this so that they both get it on focus?

Comment: Can you create a small sandbox for the problem? https://codesandbox.io/s/new?file=/src/App.js And share the link in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `active` flag is re-evaluated only on component re-render, that is why you see a change only when the state changes (e.g. by typing, which very probably triggers a state change in the parent component if it uses `onChange` for example).

In your case, it seems you could just use the `onFocus` and `onBlur` listeners directly, and have the `active` flag as a state:

```
export const FormInput = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>(function FormInput(props, ref) {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)

  const labelClassName = classNames(
    active && styles.active
  )

  return (
    <div className={labelClassName}>
      <input
        onFocus={() => setActive(true)}
        onBlur={() => setActive(false)}
      />
    </div>
  )
})
```